# Preventing a user from logging in if they have a certain permission level

Tags: php, validation, permissions

I am trying to block a user from logging in if they do not have a certain group# (permission level) is a user has the permission level of 1(bench) or 6(denied) I want a message to show up and kill the code, not allowing them to login - or allowing them to login enough to where the code recognizes they do not have permission and then stopping it, then showing the message.

As of now I have it set up as a redirect back to the index page (sign in page), but do not know how to get a message to display in that fashion.

I am trying to do it the following way, but am getting a non object error. Is there a better way to do it or am I just doing something wrong with the code?

The following code is giving me the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function hasPermission() on a non-object:

```
  $denied_message = "You have been denied from using the site"; 
if($user->hasPermission('denied')) {
die($denied_message);}


$validate = new Validate();


 $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)
    ));
// added this line in
//if($user->hasPermission('1')) {
      //  die($permissionError);}

  //Added to display denied users 
  $denied_message = "You have been denied from using the Sunday Funday League"; 
if($user->hasPermission('denied')) {
die($denied_message);}

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('userIndex.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
}
```

Code for my permissions in my user class.

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Showing where $user is defined in user class.

```
public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user) {
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)) {
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                // process Logout
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->find($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `$user` is not an aboject. How do you create `$user`?

Comment: It is defined in my user class

Comment: It must not be, because if it was you'd have an object on which to call your function.

Comment: I just added in some of my user class to show where it is defined.

Comment: Just because you have a class defining the user doesn't mean that it happened.

Comment: the extra code isn't much help. What's `Session::get()` doing? and how does `$user` get stored in your object? You don't save it anywhere in the object or return it

Comment: What does `print_r($user)` output?

Comment: I did `if($user->hasPermission('denied')) {
die($denied_message);}
print_r($user);` and it came up with nothing on my page or when I tried to log in.

Comment: well, $user OBVIOUSLY isn't an object otherwise php wouldn't be saying "non-object". given you have nothing coming up, then $user isn't defined at all.

Comment: How was $user created before it was being used? Because I see you trying to use $user as a object at the top, then reusing the variable and creating another $user object somewhere at the middle